# get data from an URL with promise in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm pretty new with nodejs, and I'm trying to get data from an URL and return to the HTML page.

For now, the server.js, routes.js and controller.js files, and in the controller.js I'm trying to do this:

```
'use strict';

const https = require('https');
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),


exports.operations = function(req, res) {
var result;
    
    https.get('https://my/link', (res) => {
  

    res.on('data', (d) => {
        //process.stdout.write(d);
        result += d;
    });

    res.on('end', () => {
        console.log("HERE ", result);
      });

    }).on('error', (e) => {
    console.error(e);
    });
```

Anyway, I think that if I want to send the result to the html, adding before the last `});` the line

```
res.render('index', { title: 'Hey', message: JSON.stringify(result, null, 4) });
```

then I need to use promises, like `.then()` or similar. But I absolutely don't get how to make it on nodejs (I knew how to do in angularJS anyway).

How can I get it to work?

UPDATE: any suggestions about libraries to use are welcome!

Comment: What do you mean by sending the result to the html?

Comment: well you're right, I did not wrote i am using the `pug` module; with pug you can write `res.render(message: "hello")` and this "hello" will be written on the html page you previously chose. Basicly, I need to use the data once i have retrieved it, for example saving the JSON i receive from `https://my/link` in a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios#example) for http requests.

It is fairly self explanatory to use. An example of this is:

```
axios.get('/user', {
    params: {
      ID: 12345
    }
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
  .then(function () {
    // always executed
  });
```

Comment: thanks, that's was exactly what i was searching for! Since I'm new to nodejs i don't know the module names i need =)

Just a question, the last .then is executed anyway when the promise is anyway resolved?

Comment: No worries at all :) Good luck with it.